# How to list all music in MediaStore without app songs

Tags: android, audio-player, mpmusicplayercontroller, audio, android-music-player

I used this code to get all music in MediaStore but not only music, my list has all music in my device and application's sound like "facebook" or "skype". How to avoid that?

```
public void getSongList(){
    //query external audio
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Toast.makeText(PlayListActivity.this, musicUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    //iterate over results if valid
    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        //add songs to list
        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        do {
            String path = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            long thisAlbumId = musicCursor.getLong(albumColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisAlbumId, thisTitle, thisArtist, path));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain about this but I did it in the following way.

```
public void getSongList(){
//query external audio
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Toast.makeText(PlayListActivity.this, musicUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
//iterate over results if valid
if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
    //get columns
    int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
    int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
    int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
    int songDuration  = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DUration);
    //add songs to list
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
    do {
        String path = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
        long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
        long thisAlbumId = musicCursor.getLong(albumColumn);
        String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
        String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
        int dur  =       Integer.parseInt(musicCursor.getString(songDuration));
        if(dur>5000){
        songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisAlbumId, thisTitle, thisArtist, path));}
        }
         while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Another way might be to do it with directory maybe?